# SELECT SUM(CRC32(column)) LIMIT doesn't work

Tags: mysql

I need to get the checksum of a specific column and specific number of rows using `LIMIT`.

`SELECT SUM(CRC32(column)) FROM table LIMIT 0, 100;`

But, the value returned is the checksum of the entire table. Why does that happen? How can I use LIMIT to get the checksum of only a specific number of rows?

The following works:

`SELECT SUM(CRC32(column)) FROM table WHERE id > 0 AND id < 101;`

But I don't want to use this method because of potential jumps in the auto_increment value.

Comment: Wait a minute, what are you trying to do here? Adding together CRC32 values doesn't do anything particularly meaningful.

Comment: im verifying 2 tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does that happen?

`LIMIT` gets applied after aggregate functions.

When used without `GROUP BY`, `SUM` aggregates over the whole table, leaving you with only one record, which falls under the `LIMIT`.

Use this:

```
SELECT  SUM(CRC32(column))
FROM    (
        SELECT  column
        FROM    mytable
        ORDER BY
                id
        LIMIT   100
        ) q
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
  SELECT SUM(CRC32(column)) FROM 
    (SELECT column FROM table LIMIT 0, 100) AS tmp;
```